# uploading image to website and rename

Tags: php, image, upload

When adding a new item to my website I search for the picture of the item to upload to my site.  After finding the file and completing the form I click add.  This is supposed to take my local picture and store it to my images/rental directory.  In addition, the picture will automatically be named after the item number and add thumb to the filename (ex:109_thumb.jpg).

Here is the code that I have tried after changing directories, but can't get it to work again yet.

```
<tr>
<td align="right" class="tdTextBold">Thumb Image:           
</td>
<td><font class="errMsgB">*</font></td>
<td align="left">
<input  id="fiuImage1" type="file"  name="fileRentalThumbImage" /><div class="VCenter100" id="preview3" align="center"><?  if ($rentalThumbImage!="" && $rentalThumbImage!=null)?><img src="../<? echo $rentalThumbImage; ?>" width="80" height="100"  /></div> 
<!--<div class="column">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tr>

<td>
<? 
if ($rentalThumbImage!="" && $rentalThumbImage!=null)
{
?>
<div class="VCenter100" id="preview1" align="center"><?  if ($rentalThumbImage!="" && $rentalThumbImage!=null)?><img src="../<? echo $rentalThumbImage; ?>" /></div>
<?
}
else
{
?>
<div class="VCenter100" id="preview1" align="center">Thumb Image</div>
<?
}
?>          
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<div class="column">
<div class="file_button">
<input id="uploadButton" style="WIDTH: 120px" type="button" value="Browse" name="file1" />  <input class="hiddenMask" id="fiuImage1" type="file" onchange="prePicture(this.name,'preview1')" name="fileRentalThumbImage" /> 
</div>
<input style="WIDTH: 100px" onclick="document.frmMovie.rentalThumbImage.value='';removeImage('fiuImage1','preview1'); get('haveImage1').value='N';" type="button"  value="Delete" name="remoteImage1"/> 
</div>
<div style="CLEAR: both">   
     </div>                             </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>     
</div>
```

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to either upload the image to your server then display it or use the HTML 5 file API. Since you are using PHP, here's an example of the former:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <input  id="fiuImage1" type="file"  name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <div class="VCenter100" id="preview3" align="center">
        <?php
            if( $_FILES["file"] ) {

                if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                    "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                    //Stored in: upload/$_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }
                ?>
                <img src="upload/<?= $_FILES["file"]["name"] ?>" width="80" height="100"  />
                <?php
            }

        ?>
    </div>  
</form>
```